# JavaScript & HTML Forms: Which button is the submitter?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I am writing a JavaScript function to pre-process form data. One thing I need to know is which of a number of submit buttons was used.

Roughly, the script has the following outline.

```
var form=document.querySelector('form#test');
form.onsubmit=processForm;
function processForm() {
    //  how did I get here
}

<form id="test">
    <!-- usual stuff -->
    <button type="submit" name="check">Check</button>
    <button type="submit" name="doit">Do Stuff</button>
</form>
```

I know that I could attach the function to the individual submit buttons, but it would be more resilient if I attached it to the form itself.

Is there a form property or some other method for checking which submit button was used?

Thanks

Comment: *"It would be more resilient"* How?

Comment: @4castle Why is it wonky? I have multiple buttons, all wanting pre-processing. In principle I could also send a `submit()` call, which would bypass the buttons, and hence the `onclick` altoghether.

Comment: @StephenRoss That has never been true. `<button type="submit" name="doit">Do It</button>` is functionally equivalent to `<input type="submit" name="doit" value="Do It">`.

Comment: @4castle Resilient in that you only need to know about the form itself, rather than which buttons are possible submitters. Given that you can submit a form using `<input type="submit">`, `<button>` or `<button type="submit">`, as well as `form.submit()`, checking the `submit` event is much more manageable.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach `click` handler to each `<button>` element, create a variable to store clicked `button` `name` property, or reference to element, access property or element at `submit` event

```
function processForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(curr) // `curr`: `name` of clicked `button"` element
}

var submit = document.querySelectorAll("button[type=submit]");
var curr;
for (var i = 0; i < submit.length; i++) {
  submit[i].onclick = function(e) {
    curr = e.target.name; // store reference to `name`, or element
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the clicked submit button is sent as it is considered active. 
I believe that when there is only 1 submit button the form will submit on enter but when multiple it will only submit on click.

Thus in your backend, you can just check for the existence of either form button to know which button was used.

Relevant section of HTML rfc:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2

However I wasn't able to find a good browser compatibility for this so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to my question is that you can’t. Once the `submit` event is activated, it doesn’t seem to know or care how it got there.

The only solution, as mentioned in my original question, is to attach a listener to the submit button[s].

Here is a stub of the processing code:

```
window.onload=init;

function init() {

    var form=document.querySelector('form#test');
    var submitButtons=form.querySelectorAll('button:not([type]),button[type="submit"],input[type="submit"]');
    if(submitButtons.length) {
        for(var i=0;i<submitButtons.length;i++) submitButtons[i].addEventListener('click',process);
    }
    function process(e) {
        var submitter=this;
        var form=this.form;
        //  etc
    }
}
```

Oh well …